# ADODB.Recordset data cannot bind into datagridview

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

i wan to bind data from recordset into data grid view, but the data cannot show in the grid view, i try count the row, there are 2 rows of data, but cannot bind into grid view

```
If Not rs.EOF Then                    
    DataGridView1.DataSource = rs
    DataGridView1.Refresh()
Else
    MsgBox("Record Not Founds  " & txtSearch.Text, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
End If
```

Comment: what kind of error are you getting?

Comment: no error, no data show in grid view only

Comment: What's your sql? What's your datagrid definition?

Comment: no error for my sql, i declare that grid view as  New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView

Comment: try this tutorial : http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-binding-a-datagridview-to-a-database

Answer (score 2):

You can't bind a DataGridView to an ADODB.Recordset. If you can't change the data source to  ADO.Net then you will have to pre-process the recordset into something the DataGridView can bind to like a DataTable, or alternatively just write the rows in manually.

Answer (score 1):

@Stuart's answer is correct.

You could use the code on [this site](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/DataTableToRecordset.aspx) to convert your `recordset` to a `datatable` but note the [problem I experienced here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103756/strange-error-appending-fields-to-recordset-in-vs2010-after-converting-to-net-4) when I upgraded to .NET 4

Your best solution is to query your data with something that can handle datatables/datasets - what is your db?