# Missing method 'instance void MYDLLNAME ADODB.Fields...'

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, adodb

Have rewritten some parts of the application from VB.Net to C#. Everything is working as expected for all but one user. This user is getting this error message:

Error: Missing method 'instance void MYDLLNAME ADODB.Fields::Append(string,valuetype ADODB.DataTypeEnum,int32,valuetype ADODB.FieldAttributeEnum,object)' from class 'ADODB.InternalFields'

Is there a component potentially missing on the end user machine and is there a way to solve this or is it best to go away from ADODB.Recordset to ADO.Net Dataset?

Have seen the following questions, but they do not really solve my problem. Not upgraded framework, was already 4.5, VS 2017 used.

[Strange error appending fields to recordset in VS2010 after converting to .NET 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103756/strange-error-appending-fields-to-recordset-in-vs2010-after-converting-to-net-4)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f84cdc9c-f684-46d6-9b6f-757d047b00d5/fieldsappend?forum=Vsexpressvb

P.S. Using COM is not an option in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by setting properties of reference to ADODB in the project to:

- Embed Interop = false
- Copy Local = true

These are inverted defaults.